# gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs does not install client libs (but does generate them)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, android-studio

I am working on an android project working in Android Studio (0.5.3).

I have created two endpoint api classes (called `UserEndpoint` and `OfferEndpoint`) in the backend part of the project. Then I wanted to create the client libraries to use in the app part of the project. I use the `gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs` command for this. In the `/build/client-libs` part it did create the .zip files of the client libraries. But it did not install them in the app part of the project.

So now my question:

Is the command I am using (`gradlew appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibs`) supposed to also install them in the app part, and if yes what could be the reason it is not working for me (there seem to be no errors).

[This tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android) mentions that I have to manually add the libraries. I added the .zip files to the /libs folder, but there is no 'add as library' option as the tutorial mentions. Is this the correct way of doing this? And if yes could someone give me a little more in detail explanation because I tried some things by adding the dependency in the build.gradle file but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, if you don't use `@ApiNamespace`, the namespace that is used
>   is the reverse of `your-project-id.appspot.com`. That is, the package
>   path will be `com.appspot.your-project-id.yourApi`.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apinamespace)

The annotation was missing in the @Api annotations of the endpoints.